# OR Condition in htaccess URL re-writing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have done a URL re-writing in my `.htaccess` file for `manage_districts.php` as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?editid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?delid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here you can see that for both, **edit and delete** operations I have a same page so, instead of writing the same rule for the same file I want to write a single rule where I can pass the `editid` as well as `delid` with an **OR Condition**.

I have already tried this syntax,

```
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?(editid|delid)=$1 [NC,L]
```

but it's not working.

Comment: I don't understand. You want both editid and delid to get the parameter? Then why not manage_districts.php?editid=$1&delid=$1 [NC,L]  ???

Comment: @ Amarnasan I didn't try that. Wait...will let u know. Thanks !

Comment: nope. it's deleting my record when I am clicking on the Edit Button

Comment: Uh? What "Edit" button? What are you talking button? Are you using some sort of config manager?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo COLLEGE_INFO_ADMIN_BASE_PATH ?>manageDistricts/<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="Edit">Edit</a><a href="<?php echo COLLEGE_INFO_ADMIN_BASE_PATH ?>manageDistricts/<?php echo $row['id']?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure,You want to delete this Record?');" title="Delete">Delete</a>

Comment: I think you are confused about what you are trying to achieve here. Give us examples of incoming urls and what you would like them to be re-written to. Your current rules will not help you with anything as you have the L flag on each (i.e. 'Last - stop processing rules') so the second rule will never run. As it stands manageDistricts/{num} will always just give you: manage_districts.php?editid={num}

Comment: Man... you can't use the SAME url to achieve TWO different actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same URL for two different actions. So, add a second parameter with values either "edit" or "delete".

```
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/edit/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?editid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/delete/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?delid=$1 [NC,L]
```

And in your html:

```
<a href="<?php echo COLLEGE_INFO_ADMIN_BASE_PATH ?>manageDistricts/edit/<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="Edit">Edit</a>

<a href="<?php echo COLLEGE_INFO_ADMIN_BASE_PATH ?>manageDistricts/delete/<?php echo $row['id']?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure,You want to delete this Record?');" title="Delete">Delete</a>
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?editid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^manageDistricts/([0-9]+)/?$ manage_districts.php?delid=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: That's not what I wrote.

Comment: so it's impossible to pass two keywords in the same rule or for two different action ?

Comment: @vitally That's not what you were doing though - the first part of the RewriteRule is the incoming url and both were identical in your code